# How to connect two robot arms by sharing one manipulator in webots

Tags: webots

I am working on a project that two robot arms control a rope to play a toy. I want to first simulate it in webots. **Each robot arm has a stick as the end-effector. And there is a rope connecting both the two sticks.** However, in webots simulation, each robot(let's say UR5e) should be set as an independent node. How can I connect them using a rope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Connector](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/connector) node to connect the end of the rope to the second robot stick.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I find it helpful and will try it.